# meaning of this please??----So that's twenty of each sort, right?

Tags: sentence-meaning

What is the meaning of this please?

> So that's twenty of each sort, right?

Comment: Customer: *Do you have small widgets and large widgets? I need 20* Shop assistant: *hold on I'll just go and check... yes we've got plenty of both. So that's 20 of each sort, right?* In other words it means 20 of each type, not 20 in total.

Comment: More information is required. The meaning depends upon the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*Of each sort*" means there are probably different kinds or types of a thing and one is referring to each of that type.
So, "*Twenty of each sort*" means 20 of each kind of that product.

For example, if there are 4 types of bottles, lets say blue, green, red and yellow, then twenty bottles of each. (20 blue, 20 green, 20 red and 20 yellow)